# Mixpanel to biggquery daily / monthly export limit

Tags: google-bigquery, mixpanel

So GA4 has this export limit of 1 Million events per day to bigquery. I want to know if Mixpanel has any similar daily / monthly limit.

I have searched online, but can't seem to find any relevant information. I basically want to use the platform with the most generous export limit to bigquery.

Also, is it necessary to have an intermediate platform like GA4 or Mixpanel etc, or can I directly send raw data to bigquery without any limits?